# Add dynamic filter expression OR with script 2.0 in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I want to add filters with OR condition dynamically to the search object in script 2.0.

Comment: You can install the extension : "NetSuite: Search Export" on Chrome, then create the Saved Search in Netsuite UI : once saved, when you open the Saved Search for edition, you will see, at the top right, a link to export the Saved Search : it will give you the ss1.0 and ss2.0 of the saved search.

Answer (score 4):

You can use filter expressions to add `and/or` operators.
As per [NetSuite](https://system.na3.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_458440490721.html)

> Use filter expressions as a shortcut to create filters (search.Filter).

eg. search filter like

```
search.createFilter({
  name: 'transactionnumber',
  operator: 'is',
  values: 'ABC'
});
```

can be replaced with

```
[['transactionnumber', 'is', 'ABC'], 'or', ['transactionnumber', 'is', 'XYZ']]
```

In essence, Search Filters are array or array joined together with operators.

Comment: Have tried this. when I create expression and add it back to filters it gives me an error.  Wrong parameter type: filters[0] is expected as Filter.

Comment: var defaultFilters = searchObj.filters; When I add expression back to default filters it give error.

Comment: var defaultFilters = searchItemStockObj.filters;                        
 customFilters.push([ ['transactionnumber','is','abc' ],'OR',['transactionnumber','is','xyz' ] ]);                     
  defaultFilters.push(customFilters);
  searchItemStockObj.filters =  defaultFilters;

Comment: Try this
`var defaultFilters = searchItemStockObj.filterExpression; 
if (customFilters.length > 0) { 
  customFilters.push('AND'); 
}
customFilters.push([ ['transactionnumber','is','abc' ],'OR',['transactionnumber','is','xyz' ] ]); 
defaultFilters.push(customFilters); 
searchItemStockObj.filterExpression = defaultFilters;`

Comment: Thank you Avi. I have tried this but it gives me Malformed search filter expression error.

Comment: Filters variables were not handelled correctly. `var defaultFilters = searchItemStockObj.filterExpression; 
if (defaultFilters.length > 0) { 
  defaultFilters.push('AND'); 
} 
defaultFilters.push([ ['transactionnumber','is','abc' ],'OR',['transactionnumber','is','xyz' ] ]); 
defaultFilters.push(defaultFilters); 
searchItemStockObj.filterExpression = defaultFilters;`

Comment: This gives me java.lang.StackOverflowError.

Comment: You can install the extension : NetSuite: Search Export on Chrome, then create the Saved Search in Netsuite UI : once saved, when you open the Saved Search for edition, you will see, at the top right, a link to export the Saved Search : it will give you the ss1.0 and ss2.0 of the saved search.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.  This is what worked for me:

```js
var soLines = salesOrder.lineItems;
var filteredIDs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < soLines.length; i++) {
    filteredIDs.push(['customid', 'is', soLines[i].customID])
    filteredIDs.push('OR');
}
filteredIDs.pop();

var mySearch = search.create({
    type: search.Type.SALES_ORDER
    join: 'item',
    columns: [
        "internalid",
        "item.itemid",
        "customid"
    ],
    filters: [filteredIDs]
});
```

The trick is to create the filter before the search is created.  Then you can assign the filtered list as your **filters**